# Unable to delete field from IndexedDB using id as primary key

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb, dexie

I am trying to delete a record form indexeddb and in service I have created a function to delete by `primary key: id` . Field is not getting deleted.

Also I am getting a warning as `Unhandled rejection: TypeError: Invalid key provided. Keys must be of type string, number, Date or Array<string | number | Date>.`

**Service:**

```
private todos: Todo[] = [];
private db: any;

deleteIndexDb(id: string) {
 this.todos = this.todos
      .filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
    return this.db.todos.where('id').equals(id).delete()
      //return this.db.todos.table.delete()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Database successfully deleted");
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error("Could not delete database");
      });
  }
```

**Model:-**

```
export class Todo {
    public id: string;
    public value: string
  }
```

**Component:**

```
form: FormGroup;
todos: Todo[] = [];

  constructor(private readonly todoService: TodoService,
    public readonly onlineOfflineService: OnlineOfflineService){
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      value: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }
deleteUser(todos) {
    this.todoService.deleteIndexDb(todos.id);
  }
```

**HTML:-**

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li *ngFor="let item of todos; let i = index" class="todo-item">
      <span [ngClass]="{ inactive: item.done }">{{ item.value }}</span>

      <button class="todo-item-button" (click)="editUser()">Edit</button>
      <button class="todo-delete-button" (click)="deleteUser(todos)">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: you should send "item", not todos: `(click)="deleteUser(item)"` else you're passing all the array

Comment: Please take more time when asking questions on StackOverflow. Please attempt to use proper grammar and code formatting.